# How to wrap words in table which contains Unicode character '\u00A0'

Tags: javascript, html, regex, unicode, whitespace

When my string have spaces words get wrap in table. But because I wanted to preserve spaces in innerHTML so I replaced it with '\u00A0' .

```
var newString = aString.replace(/\s/g,'\u00A0');
```

Now when newString gets render in the Table,  It is not wrapping up because I have replaced white spaces with  corresponding Unicode character.

```
getTableRow(rowIndex).cells(i).innerHTML = myRow[i]; //Here You can replace myRow[i] with newString
```

word-wrap CSS property is not working for me.

In short I have  used \u00A0 to prevent consecutive spaces from collapsing to a single space but don’t really want to prevent line breaks.

Comment: You seem to be asking “how can I prevent myself from eating a cake and eat a cake?” If you show us some code or some URL, someone might guess what you really mean. Do you mean that you used `\u00A0` to prevent *consecutive* spaces from collapsing to a single space but don’t really want to prevent line breaks? Then there’s probably a better approach to the original problem.

Comment: It sounds to me like what you actually want to do is set a width maximum for some individual table cells. Is the problem that things wrap ugly, or don't wrap soon enough (lines too long) or should not wrap on particular phrases? It seems likely that by tuning the widths of the columns of your table you can get a long way down the line fixing this.

Comment: Apology my mistake . I have updated my question. Please have a look.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela , You are right I used \u00A0 to prevent consecutive spaces from collapsing to a single space but don’t really want to prevent line breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution .

Replace white space with brakable visible Unicode character ie "\u2009". It is working perfectly for me.

```
newString = aString.replace(/\s/g,'\u2009');
getTableRow(rowIndex).cells(i).innerHTML = newString;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you can insert the following tag to tell the browser that it can wrap the text at a certain point.

```
<wbr>
```

For more information on this tag, follow this link: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_wbr.asp

The only snag is that IE does not support this tag yet (as of IE9) as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since IE does not support this tag and my application runs only in IE, I can not use this

Comment: IE has supported `<wbr>` for a long time, though new versions have issues with the support, see http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nobr.html#wbr

Comment: Thank you for notifying me! I didn't know that

Answer (score 1):

Instead of replacing spaces by no-break spaces (`\u00A0`), just set [`white-space`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#propdef-white-space): pre-wrap on the element in CSS. [Browser support](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html) is fairly good, including IE 8.

But if you need to cover IE 7 and earlier, too, use your current approach but so that you only replace the second space of any pair of consecutive spaces:

```
aString.replace(/\s\s/g,'\u00A0 ')
```